# java - read large xml file and get byte position of elements

Tags: java, xml

I am using the

`javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory`

to walk through a 13GB wikipedia xml file.

Now I want to know at which byte position a `<page>` tag line starts so that I can jump there and read it.

Here is some code:

```
inputStream = new FileInputStream(xmlFile); // I am free to change this

XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance(); // maybe there is a better way?
eventReader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(inputStream);


// this is in a loop
event = eventReader.nextEvent();

if (event.isStartElement()) {
    StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();

    if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart() == "page") {
         // !!! here I want to know the byte position in the file
    }
}
```

What I tried:

```
inputStream.getChannel().position()
```

and

```
inputStream.getChannel().position(...)
```

to jump to the position where the tag was and to read the tag. But this does not work because the `eventReader` reads chunks of approx 8000 bytes.

Comment: see this http://andreinc.net/2013/12/09/java-7-nio-2-how-to-use-seekablebytechannel-interface-for-random-access-to-files-raf/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the encoding:

```
eventReader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(inputStream, "ASCII");
```

Comment: Wikipedia files are in UTF-8, not ASCII.

Comment: That is right but then `getLocation()` returns the UTF-8 index which means that I would need to read the whole file before I know the byte index.

Comment: What evidence do you have for that?

Comment: I tried it out. The index was smaller and the XML reader crashed when I set the channel position. (There were umlauts before the second page tag).

Comment: In any case, you'll get incorrect strings when there are umlauts around or any other nonascii text. The doc for Location.getCharacterOffset() contradicts your experience. Try woodstox?

Comment: I will add some more text and then try it out again without the wong encoding. If it works, I will remove this answer to not contradict.

Answer (score 0):

To learn where an element came from in an XML stream, call `getLocation()`.

You can't use this to magically make the XML reading process start in the middle, an XML file has to be read in order.